# FBA with two factor auth

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication

I know the question is short, but I have never done this before, on SP2013 on premises.

I need to configure FBA with 2 factor auth, can anyone guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bunch of `addIdentity` methods in the JSch class, which can be used to provide a key pair for public key authentication, and there is a `setPassword` method in the Session class.

I would simply use both and try to connect to the server.

The SSH protocol is made such that the server presents a set of authentication options in each step, and the client then selects of those one that it supports, and if I remember the code right, JSch simply does this.

Please report back if this actually worked, I didn't try it.

Comment: please ellaborate more y our answer, what is the JSch class?

Comment: You can follow these steps mentioned in http://magenic.com/Blog/Post/40/Multi-Factor-Authentication-on-SharePoint-using-AD-DS